# How to port CGAL to android and run examples

Tags: android, cross-compiling, cgal

CGAL has provided a [documentation](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/Cross-Compilation-of-CGAL-for-Android) for this. So far I was able to cross compile CGAL with headers only and without CGAL core. But I want to compile CGAL with  CGAL core. I have cross compiled the boost library as static. How do I set appropriate cmake variables ? 
And how do I generate dynamic lib file of CGAL?